# swiftのAVAudioPlayerのループ再生

Tags: ios, swift

AVAudioPlayerのループ再生方法がわかりません。
ご存知の方いらっしゃいませんか？

Comment: なにはともあれ、クラスリファレンスを調べる。[AVAudioPlayer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioPlayer/numberOfLoops)それを習慣づけるようにしましょう。

Comment: http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1678/%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%AE%E4%BB%95%E6%96%B9%E3%81%8C%E8%89%AF%E3%81%84%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF%E8%A8%80%E3%81%84%E9%9B%A3%E3%81%84%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89%E8%89%AF%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B

Answer (score 2):

AVAudioPlayerのnumberOfLoopsというプロパティに値を設定してあげるとループ再生が出来ます。

無限ループさせる場合は、numberOfLoopsに-1の値を設定すれば出来ると思います。